# Is there a way to tell anchor to ignore a field on deserilize?

Tags: anchor, anchor-program-idl, anchor-lang

We are facing an issue. Appreciate it if you can give some suggestions.

We have several `AccountExample` in mainnet/devnet.

It is created the following way.

```
#[account]
pub struct AccountExample {
    pub fieldOne: u64,
    pub fieldTwo: u64,
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateExample<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    proposer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = proposer,
        space = 8 + 8 + 8,
    )]
    multisig: Box<Account<'info, AccountExample>>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

We have an instruction to do something with the account.

```
pub struct DoSomething<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    example: Box<Account<'info, AccountExample>>,
}
```

---

We change the above code to this and have pushed it.

```
#[account]
pub struct AccountExample {
    pub fieldOne: u64,
    pub fieldTwo: u64,
    pub fieldThree: u64,
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateExample<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    proposer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = proposer,
        space = 8 + 8 + 8 + 8,
    )]
    multisig: Box<Account<'info, AccountExample>>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

When we try to call `DoSomething` with older `AccountExample`, we are facing with the following issue.

```
Program log: AnchorError caused by account: example. Error Code: AccountDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 3003. Error Message: Failed to deserialize the account.
```

Is this because of the size difference between older (8+8+8) and newer (8+8+8+8) versions of `AccountExample`?

If so is there a way for us to tell anchor to ignore `fieldThree` when deserialing?

Appreciate if anyone can help us figure out this issue.

Comment: This looks like a case to migrate the account. example in cookbook: https://solanacookbook.com/guides/data-migration.html#how-can-you-migrate-a-program-s-data-accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You've maneuvered yourselves in a corner now.

It would have been best to use a new struct name when you make changes, such as ExampleV1 and ExampleV2.

They are really different structs, with different sizes.

You could read the account first, check its length, and then either call DoSomethingV1 or DoSomethingV2, depending on what length you found.

You can also try replacing `AccountExample` with `AccountInfo` in the DoSomething definition:

```
pub struct DoSomething<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    example: Box<Account<'info, AccountInfo>>,
}
```

You might need to add a `/// CHECK comment` if the compiler complains.